# .setError not going away

Tags: android

I am trying to use multiple .setError on EditTexts. It works but when I retype the error message for 'achternaam', 'klascode' and 'reden' wont go away and I cant start my AsyncTask. I can't find any error in here. I can't find another way to validate all EditText using .setError.

```
            boolean failFlag = false;

            if (et_voornaam.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_voornaam.setError("Voer voornaam in");
                failFlag = true;

            }

            if (et_achternaam.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_achternaam.setError("Voer achternaam in");
                failFlag = true;
            }

            if (et_studentnummer.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_studentnummer.setError("Voer studentnummer in");
                failFlag = true;
            }

            if (et_klascode.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_klascode.setError("Voer klascode in");
                failFlag = true;
            }
            if (et_mobiel.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_mobiel.setError("Voer mobiele nummer in");
                failFlag = true;
            }
            if (et_geboortedatum.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_geboortedatum.setError("Voer geboortedatum in");
                failFlag = true;
            }
            if (et_datumAfwezigheid.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_datumAfwezigheid.setError("Voer datum van afwezigheid in");
                failFlag = true;
            }
            if (et_datumWeerAanwezig.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_datumWeerAanwezig.setError("Voer datum van weer aanwezig in");
                failFlag = true;
            }
            if (et_reden.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                et_reden.setError("Voer reden in");
                failFlag = true;
            }


            if (failFlag = false) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                        .setMessage("Weet je het zeker?")

                        .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                                Log.d("TEST:Input=", "Ja");
                            }

                        }).setNegativeButton("Nee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Log.d("TEST:Input=", "Nee");
                    }
                }).show();
            } else failFlag = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Niet alle velden zijn correct ingevuld.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });
```

Comment: Try this: instead of your_edit_text.getText().toString().length() <= 0 use  your_edit_text.getText().toString().matches("")

Comment: @Krupal, even better: `TextUtils.isEmpty(edit_text.getText());` That checks for null, and empty spaces.

Comment: @Binghammer ya..it is even better...Regular Expression in .matches("") will also work always.